# How do I use this motor shield?

Tags: power, motor, arduino-motor-shield

[image]

I am stuck with this motor shield. All I have is the shield. No documentation available online, nothing.

I need to run two motors off this thing and I only have a few hours to figure out how this works.

Can anyone point me in the right direction..?
Like how to control the 2 motors that I have from it (if they could be plugged into the pins right on top of that green thing with screws, that would be great) and where to plug in the power supply?

I've seen a lot of weird motor controllers for Arduino, this one I just can't figure out.

Comment: What chip is that?

Comment: Just a little bit of googling and here it is. It is based on L293D, it is quite a common one. In that link there is PDF but you have to login there in order to read it. 
https://www.robomart.com/l293d-motor-driver-shield?dtags%5B0%5D=13

Comment: @Sener Damn... I must be going blind.
Thanks a lot